# Code deduplication and copy-and-swap idiom, why not using placement new?

Tags: c++

In this really interesting [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550#3279550) about the copy-and-swap idiom, it is mentioned that we create a `swap()` method in order to avoid code deduplication while creating an assignment operator, when we already have a working copy constructor and a destructor.

Instead of creating a `swap()` method just for this purpose, why not just implementing the assignment operator directly with a call to the destructor (`this->~MyClass()`, not using the keyword `delete`) following by a call to the copy constructor via placement `new` ?

Considering the exception guarantee :

If the assignment fails with an exception (the copy-and-swap version calls the copy constructor as well), is it still a good idea to continue to use the object in his old state ? I mean at this point the caller do not plan to use the old object anymore because he has a new one.

Comment: You missed quoting this bit _" and providing a strong exception guarantee."_

Comment: Think what happens if the constructor throws an exception

Comment: I understand but if the assignment fails with an exception, is it still a good idea to continue to use the object in his old state ? I mean at this point the caller do not plan to use the old object anymore because he has a new one

Comment: The point is to ensure that if an exception is thrown in the assignment, the assigned-to object remains in the state it was before the assignment was attempted.

Comment: @juanchopanza please see my comment

Comment: @mikeDundee The point is in that in some situations you want assignments to have roll-back semantics under exceptions. Copy and swap is a way to guarantee that. If you don't need it, then there is little point in using it, because it can have a performance impact for no gain.

Comment: @juanchopanza : I see the assignment can be just a part of a set of instructions that you may want to rollback